# Three column layout: fixed width center with fluid side columns

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to implement a design in CSS that will have a tiled background on the
body. I want to use a png image in the content background as an oval-shaped 
opacity mask over the body background. The side columns (and a propped footer 
with clipped overflow) will have a partially opaque black background that will 
match the edges of the .png mask.

The intention is to have a fixed dimension center area with a complex background
pattern that will fill any size browser window.

I can't think how I would pull this off. `margin:auto` does not seem like it will
be sufficient for my background requirement and I don't think I can add a 
large fixed prop to the side-columns without losing my centering.

[Here's a rough mockup of the layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raaTc.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your `screenshot` you can write like this:

```
body{
 background: url(image.jpg) repeat center center;
}

.container{
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

**UPDATED:**

Solution according to your question `Three column layout: fixed width center with fluid side columns`

### http://jsfiddle.net/XMg2h/3/

But it's work in modern browsers

**UPDATED**

### http://jsfiddle.net/XMg2h/10/

it's work in all browsers

Comment: That technique will not work since there is an opacity mask over the tiled background. The center of the mask is a fixed image with varying opacity, while the edges have a uniform opacity and have to resize fluidly.

Comment: Thanks, that's the layout I'm looking for. I'd prefer to use basic CSS with no vendor-specific extensions, but if I can't find anything better, this will help. I don't think it should be very difficult to add a propped footer with hidden overflow to make the background fill the window vertically as well.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. That works better, but I notice that there is a small margin on the right. Also, if there is no text in the side columns, it does not render correctly. I think my solution will work well, but I will accept your answer since you took the time to give an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked a solution using absolute positioning. I appreciate any comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/tupCS/12/

I tried working with floats and negative margins, but the backgrounds overlapped, which would not work since I am needing this for background masks and the overlap would cause bleeding between the masks.

My solution also separates the background columns into their own div. I can then hide overflow for this div while not hiding it for the content. This allows scroll bars to appear only when the window is smaller than the content.

Answer (score 0):

Tile the background image with this CSS:

```
 body{
      background:url(wallpaper.png);
 }
```

Make the 'oval shadow' into a semi-transparent .png and cut it into four pieces. Attach the pieces to the corners of the document using absolutely positioned pseudo-elements.

```
 body:before{
      content:''; 
      display:block; 
      background:url(oval-shadow-top-left:.png);
      position:absolute; 
      top:0; left:0; 
      height:300px; width:400px;
}
```

Do this for each corner (you can use any element's pseudo-elements, as long as it's not relatively positioned).

Center the div, and give it a `z-index` to make sure it stays above the pseudo-elements.

```
 div{
      width:300px; height:200px; 
      margin: 50% auto; 
      position:relative; 
      z-index:100;
      top:-150px;
 }
```

[Demo of above techniques](http://jsfiddle.net/UWumG/)

Comment: Careful using `:before` as [it won't work in IE7 or below](http://caniuse.com/#search=before).

Comment: That's an interesting technique, especially using pseudo-elements, but I need the oval mask to be fixed in the center, while the sides and bottom will be fluid and use a fixed opacity mask

Answer (score 0):

There are several blogs that have discussed this, including [Perfect Multi-Column CSS Liquid Layouts](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts).  I'm sure if you read through it (it's really quite interesting), you'll be able to adapt it to fit your needs, if it does not already do so.

Comment: Your link seems to only discuss fully fluid layouts. I am looking for a fixed center with liquid side columns. 

I'm not just looking for cut and paste code; I do want to understand the model better. Unfortunately, CSS can be hard to master, especially since there always seem to be browser bugs to work around.

Answer (score 0):

Can you work with something like this? I can explain it more if you think that this is what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/Atjtt/

Comment: It would be similar to that, but the columns need to expand rather than the center margins expand. This is because the side columns act as a mask over a background pattern.