# HTML, 3 columns layout

Tags: css, html, inline

Hi guys i need help im changing my website from tables to divs

My problem is my website needs 3 divs inline i need a div in the centre of the page 788px the other 2 are on the left and right they will have a background image on repeat that increases and decreases depending on the screen resolution but the div in the center must stay the same size and it must stay in the centre of the page no matter what resolution. Is this possible using divs?

Comment: please paste your example, what you tryed??

Comment: anything is possible, but we can help as long as you show us your code and see what is wrong with it

Answer (score 3):

This is of course possible:
I would suggest looking at float (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)
And background image (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

To set a background image:

```
<div style="background-image:url('location/image.ext');">
```

Check out background repeating : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

As for a 3 column layout example, there are tons around the net, a simple one found here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/basic-3-column-fixed-width-css-layout/

```
    <div id="container">

    <div id="left">
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>

</div>

#container {
    width: 700px;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

#content {
    padding: 0 210px 0 160px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: it's just that you're making references to w3schools, which is known to some (including a lot of SO members) people as a site where a lot of incorrect or inaccurate information is supplied.

Comment: A one sided view, you're missing out the oodles of code it has that is correct.  The links I have used to w3c are all valid/correct.  Not sure propaganda has any place here

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

Have seperate id's for each div and try using pixels for values instead of percentages... and use position as relative or fixed... so that when browser is reduced it wont change...

eg. say, you have a id for center div as #center_div... then try this...

```
#center_div{
position:relative (or fixed);
width: (value)px;
height: (value)px;
display: block;
}
```

And if you want the center div to appear on top of the other two divs... just use z-index property...

Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

What you want (liquid sides with fixed center) is already answered in this other SO post:

[Three column layout: fixed width center with fluid side columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283225/three-column-layout-fixed-width-center-with-fluid-side-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

You would need to set the middle column to a fixed-width (px) instead of %.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like that?
http://jsfiddle.net/UY5XY/5/

```
<div id="containter">
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="center">CENTER</div>
    <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#containter div {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#containter div {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
}
#left {
    left:0;            
}
#center {
    width:10%;
    margin:0 40%;
}
#right {
    right:0;   
}
```

-> text-align for IE (should be OK)
-> margins: left and right are on 0
-> center margin is percent value, but can be eg. 50px, but than you should make center margin also like 'margin: 0 50px'.