# CSS align div 1 to center and div 2 to right align

Tags: html, css

Please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/1/

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            LEFT
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            RIGHT
        </div>
</div>
```

Can we align left side block to center of the page and right side in remaining place..?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/1/ here is code

Comment: is container always going to be the given resolution?

Comment: Container = 450px Left = 300px Right = 100px, if you were to center Left in Container it would be 75px in from either side, this does not leave enough room for the Right div. Unless you want overlapping?

Comment: I think with the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283225/three-column-layout-fixed-width-center-with-fluid-side-columns) you get what you are looking for (fixed center, fluid right) if you hide the left column.

Comment: I didn't quite get it, you want the .left div centered and the right div occuping the rest of the container div?

Comment: HI Lucas Lazaro yes exactly you are right I want left div center and right in remaining space let say we fix right div width: 20px.. and left div 200px but I want container had 100% width

Comment: Dear Tom Jenkin, Thank you so much for response.. I am already doing in this way with left margin but I want any properly way so in case screen resolution change then design will not distrub..

Comment: Dear Nick, Sorry I did not get your point.

Comment: Dear Hsan, Problem is I don't want to give 50% width to all three div.. I have changed center's div width to 750px now how to assign width to left and right div because I am not sure if screen size is big or small.. and if I give width to center div in percentage then it will be higher in case of screen size change..

Comment: Here I have created another fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/XMg2h/325/[/link] but same problem when screen size increase then right block will have extra space left side... sorry for poor English..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to centralize div 1 to the remaining space (container - div2), you can style container with text-align:center and float div 2 to the right.

Otherwise I'd use position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBg7Q/) for you. It will work if you use fixed width for the divs. If not just rewrite the CSS with some javascript.

**CSS:**

```
.container
{
display:block;
width:400px;
height:250px;
background-color:black; /* not necessary */
}

.center
{
width:100px;
height:240px;
background-color:white; /* not necessary */
float:left;
margin-left:150px; /*(width_of_container/2)-(width_of_center/2)*/
}

.right
{
width:100px;
height:240px;
background-color:white; /* not necessary */
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jameson for response but I want container had 100% width this idea working right in my project but I don't want to apply left margin so is there any proper way please..