# expanding the width of menu bar

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, uinavigationbar

i have created a menu and placed it at the center of the page using the following code:

```
<div id="menucontainer">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/KLDex/

The main container for menu

```
#menucontainer {
    float:left;
    width:100% ;
    height:40px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;

}
```

followed by (to position the menu bar in the center)

```
#menucontainer ul {
    width: 980px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

(style for the lists on menu )

```
#menucontainer ul li {
    float: left;
    min-width: 74px;
    height: 23px;
    margin: 2px 4px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 15px 5px 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color:#f0f1f4;
    /*border-bottom:4px #cccccc  solid;*/
    color:#5c626c;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that, I wish to stretch the 2 extras, placed on both sides, "li" to stretch all the way on each side of the website thus creating like a bar at the top.
How can it be done?

Comment: please post your markup too

Comment: You're essentially asking for the elusive fixed-center, fluid-sides 3-column layout. It's difficult without JavaScript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283225/three-column-layout-fixed-width-center-with-fluid-side-columns