# CSS - 3 div's , 1 with fixed size, others fill space

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs on my webpage horizontally next to eachother. The middle one is of fixed size. I want the others to fill up the remaining space on the page.

I made this snippet which is a simplified version of my problem:

```css
#left {
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
#middle {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
}
#right {
  background: green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id='right'>groen</div>
<div id='left'>rood</div>
<div id='middle'>fixed px blauw</div>
```

I can't use percentages, because of the middle div having fixed size.

left and right div should each have a width of `(100%-1170px)/2`

Is there an easy way to make css fill up the extra space? Or if this isn't an option is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: You MUST include ALL code inside the question, that is why you can't just post a JSFiddle.  Do not post fake code to post the question..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Three column layout: fixed width center with fluid side columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283225/three-column-layout-fixed-width-center-with-fluid-side-columns)

Comment: use table layout and do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/mpsrcmgg/1/

Comment: @Bartdude thank you, that link looks very helpful :) i'll let you know in the comments if that post solves my problem , making this a duplicate indeed

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes, your JSFiddle the exact answer for my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/mpsrcmgg/1/

You can use `table` layout `display:table` for parent and `display:table-cell` for children but you will need to change the html markup

```css
.cont {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.cont div {
  display: table-cell;
}
#left {
  background: red;
}
#middle {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
}
#right {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id='right'>groen</div>
  <div id='middle'>fixed px blauw</div>
  <div id='left'>rood</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use table propeties:
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id='right'>groen</div>
    <div id='middle'>fixed px blauw</div>
    <div id='left'>rood</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.container>div{display:table-cell;}
#left {background: red;}
#middle {
  background: blue;
  width: 500px;
}
#right {background: green;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cs5m1ays/)